# looking for to up the last meter reading out of sql database for a given month and all equipment_code

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am looking for to up the last meter reading out of sql database for a given month and all equipment_code, that have a value of '1' in the field meter_number.

```
SELECT [Company_Code]
  ,[Equipment_Code]
  ,[Meter_Number]      
  ,Max([Transaction_Date]) Last_Tran     
  ,max([meter_reading]) 
FROM [Forefront].[dbo].[EC_METER_HISTORY_MC] 

where [Meter_Number] = '1' and [Transaction_Date] < '20130101'
group by [Company_Code]
  ,[Equipment_Code]
  ,[Meter_Number]
```

Brings me the results but I only want the meter_reading field so I can use it in crystal reports.

Comment: Which database are you using? Please add the appropriate tag to your question, as each database has its own way for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last reading, which is determined by the `MAX([Transaction_Date])`, you can do this by retrieving only a single record and order the records by `[Transaction_Date]`:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  [Meter_Reading]
FROM [Forefront].[dbo].[EC_METER_HISTORY_MC] 
WHERE [Meter_Number] = '1' AND [Transaction_Date] < '20130101'
ORDER BY [Transaction_Date] DESC
```

Since you only return a single record and defined a single `[Meter_Number]`, there is no need to do a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     
  max([meter_reading]) 
FROM [Forefront].[dbo].[EC_METER_HISTORY_MC] 

where [Meter_Number] = '1' and [Transaction_Date] < '20130101'
group by [Company_Code]
  ,[Equipment_Code]
  ,[Meter_Number]
```

Comment: This will be true for when the [Meter_Reading] is only increasing, but it is not necessarily the lastest reading.